# USB generic driver binding when new device plugged in

Tags: linux-kernel, usb, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

I am trying to understand first sentence of the [commit message](https://patchwork.kernel.org/project/linux-usb/patch/20200727104644.149873-3-hadess@hadess.net/).
It says, when a new device whose new driver is available in kernel is plugged in then the new drivers probe will be called but driver core will attach generic driver to the new device.
My question if the new driver probe called when new device plugged in then how this new device will be attached to the generic driver.

Can you guide me to understand this behavior in the kernel source.

Comment: All usb devices are following the same path, generic driver -> endpoint enumeration -> interface driver attachment. There is a few exceptions, for which that patch, when standard enumeration is not working.

Comment: It doesn't say the new driver's probe will be called, it says the new driver will be modprobe()'d, which means the module will be loaded asynchronously by a user space helper if it isn't already loaded. Meanwhile, the generic USB driver will bind to the device if no better-matching USB driver is already registered. (I wonder how things used to work? Because this change is fairly recent and I don't remember this sort of thing being a problem in the past. Perhaps it used to handle the modprobe synchronously?)

Comment: User space helper to load modules asynchronously is udev or any other applications dedicated for modprobe?

Comment: @0andriy How generic driver will be used first? It seems during driver binding, usb_device_match() is called by passing base device and driver structures.In usb_device_match(), first checking whether it is a device or interface. If it is a device then checks device driver is having id_table. If the device driver doesn't have id_table then finally checking the device driver is defined a match function, if it is defined then calling the match function.As per usb_device_match(), the last option is to check match function of the device driver and call it.So how generic driver will be called first?

Comment: Yes, usually udev (or an equivalent), with some help from libkmod. The kernel just sends "uevent" messages to a netlink socket that is opened by udev. The module to be loaded is determined from a `MODALIAS` variable in the uevent message.

Comment: Regarding my earlier comment containing "I wonder how things used to work?", it seems that the [commit mentioned in the question](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=d5643d2249b279077427b2c2b2ffae9b70c95b0b) fixed a bug in 5.7 by [commit 88b7381a939d](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=88b7381a939de0fa1f1b1629c56b03dca7077309), but itself contained a bug fixed by later [commit aea850cd35ae](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=aea850cd35ae3d266fe6f93fb9edb25e4a555230).

Comment: @IanAbbott Thanks, understood the commit.